# How to access other divs with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access other `div`s nested within a `div` for my webscrapper using Python and BeautifulSoup, but there seems to be an error.

```
my_url='https://www.boohooman.com/mens/shirts/white-shirts'
data= Soup(page, "html.parser")
P_Info= Soup.findAll("div",{"class":"product-tile js-product-tile"})
content=P_Info[0]
```

Now, `content.div` prints:

```
<div itemprop="brand" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Brand">
```

And, `content.a` prints:

```
<a class="thumb-link js-canonical-link"
```

This `a` is inside the sibling `div` to the former `div`.

However, `content.div.div` prints nothing. And, `content.div.div.a` throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a')
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am basically trying to webscrape nested divs

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I am thinking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the structure of each product tile (a.k.a `content`):

( `content` ) -> ( `div` ) -> ( `div` ) + ( `div` -> `a` )

You are trying to find the anchor element `a` inside your `content`. However, this `a` is inside the second `div`. The problem with your logic is that, you are trying to find it inside the first `div` inside `content`, by calling `content.div.div` - which defaults to selecting the first div inside the `content`. But the first `div` inside `content` does not have any `a` element. So, `content.div.div` is assigned `NoneType`.

This is perfectly allowed. However, when you type: `content.div.div.a` you are trying to search inside `NoneType` object, and this throws an error that you see on the screen.

**Solution:** You need to find the second `div` (I am calling it `target`), by typing this:

`target = content.find("div", {"class":"product-image js-product-image load-bg"})`

Now, you can safely call `target.a` to get the `a` you were looking for!

**Edit:** Since your comment said that you wanted to implement logic to get all necessary information from each product on the page, here is the complete code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.boohooman.com/mens/shirts/white-shirts"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

productTiles = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product-tile js-product-tile"})

for productTile in productTiles:
    nameElement = productTile.find(
        "a", {"class": "name-link js-canonical-link"})
    name = nameElement.text.strip()
    print(f"Name: {name}")

    linkElement = productTile.find(
        "a", {"class": "thumb-link js-canonical-link"})
    link = linkElement["href"]
    link = URL + link
    print(f"Link: {link}")

    imgElement = productTile.find("img")
    imgSrc = imgElement["src"]
    print(f"Image: {imgSrc}")

    stdPriceElement = productTile.find(
        "span", {"class": "product-standard-price"})
    if stdPriceElement is not None:
        stdPrice = stdPriceElement.text.strip()
        print(f"Standard price: {stdPrice}")

    salesPriceElement = productTile.find(
        "span", {"class": "product-sales-price"})
    if salesPriceElement is not None:
        salesPrice = salesPriceElement.text.strip()
        print(f"Sales price: {salesPrice}")

    print("----------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. Thanks

Comment: It works on my system. Can you point out what error you are getting now?

Comment: It’s working now. However, what if I want to use div instead? There multiple divs, one having the price, another having the name etc… so far .div does not work but .a works. Thanks

Comment: Wait let me see the source code of the website. I will update the answer with solution to this.

Comment: Alright, I spent some time writing a complete solution, that does not involve a lot of redundant stuff. Please mark this answer as _Accepted_ if it solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, This worked. Thanks very much. Also, I don't know how to mark the accepted. Sorry!

Comment: Just click on the tick mark next to my answer. Good luck :)